# Understanding time complexity of two nested while loop

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity

The following block of code is from a function that finds the minimum number of coins required to achieve a certain amount given by the user. Here two queue "sums" and "costs" are used.

```
while(Sums.front()<=TargetSum){
    int tempSum = Sums.front(); 
    Sums.pop();
    int tempCost = Costs.front(); 
    Costs.pop();

    for(int i=0;i<TypesOfCoins;i++)
    {
        Sums.push(coins[i]+tempSum);
        Costs.push(tempCost+1);
        if(Sums.back()==TargetSum)
        {
            cout<<"Sums:"; DisplayQueue(Sums);
            cout<<"Cost:"; DisplayQueue(Costs);
            return Costs.back();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, for nested loops times complexity is the numbers of times innermost loop iterates, so time complexity for this loop should be O(n^2), shouldn't it?

Comment: What do you consider "n"? Sums.size()? TypesOfCoins?

Comment: I am considering "TypesOfCoins" as "n".

Comment: since `TypesOfCoins` (inner loop range) is a constant (does not depend on any input that is being processed), then the **complexity** is NOT n^2. And complexity of a code is NOT how many times it iterates.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Wouldn't it be O(1) complexity? I'm still learning about it, but that's what makes sense to me.

Comment: @Annabelle or OP, if a loop iterates the *same number of times* whatever the input data is (means loop range does not depend on input), then the complexity of this loop is O(1) (which is ~= will not be taking into consideration). I will provide you with a straight forward example as an answer as I think I know what you are trying to understand.

Comment: @Annabelle Done. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 1):

The two examples below have the **same complexity** even that `n` is different. And their complexity, or Big-O, is O(InputData * 1) which is O(InputData):

```
int n = 10;
FuncA(int InputData)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n is outer loop. 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < InputData; j++) 
        {
            // .. do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
int n = 100000000;
FuncB(int InputData)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < InputData; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) // n is inner loop
        {
            // .. do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

`n` is a constant, and that means any loop that depends on `n` has O(1) complexity.

`InputData` is not constant, and that means any loop that depends on `InputData` has O(InputData) complexity.

Total Complexity = Complexity of all loops => O(InputData * 1)

Note that "*Time To Finish*" for both functions is different (since `n` is bigger, hardware speed.. etc). But the "*Computation Complexity*" is the same: No matter which loop is the inner loop nor how big is the constant (`n` in this case).

**Edit:**

A nice idea: if you have a problem and you KNOW how to solve it, but it just requires 10 years of time. Would that be complex?

The answer is no, it is not complex. It is simple but just requires time. (`n` in my example is times to process something, but the process has no complexity, it is just repeated for a constant amount of time).